# Code coverage with Powermock and gradle

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-coverage, powermock, jacoco

I have used powermock in my tests. As powermock instruments the classes I'm not getting proper coverage with jacoco.

1. I can see that IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner in Android Studio gives me proper coverage when I run the tests in the IDE. How does the IDEA code coverage work?
2. I have read, offline jacoco instrumentation can be used to get the coverage. How to do this in gradle? Any gradle plugin for this?

Answer (score 1):

"Jacoco offline" is mentioned in the PowerMock [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo); and there is a link to a *maven* [example](https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/tree/master/jacoco-offline):

Worst case, you have to study how that solution works and then adapt it for Gradle.

Comment: we dropped powermock , and refactored our code, jacoco with gradle is a mess !

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with gradle, but I have managed to generate PowerMock coverage with Jacoco with maven using `powermock-module-javaagent`. Maybe you can translate this pom into a gradle file.

Just make sure you put powermock agent **after** jacoco agent:

```
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <argLine>${jacocoArgLine} -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/powermock/powermock-module-javaagent/${powermock.version}/powermock-module-javaagent-${powermock.version}.jar -noverify</argLine>
...
```

If you want to see an example, take a look at this project: https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner

Here you can see that sonar takes into account static methods and `new` statements mocked by PowerMock:

[image]

If you want to mock `new`statements make sure you use `PowerMockRule` instead of `PowerMockRunner`.

Take a look at [this test](https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner/blob/master/src/test/java/es/jfcorugedo/CalculatorConstructorTest.java)